# Is right to import Vue from 'vue' in single component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I read from this documentation: https://chartkick.com/vue

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Chartkick from 'vue-chartkick'
import Chart from 'chart.js
Vue.use(Chartkick.use(Chart))'
```

So is the right thing to add this to a single component in Vue js?
I have nested components and i want to include this chart to only one component. Shall I include this in main.js globally or locally to component?

Comment: this is fine, you're not loading a brand new instance of Vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is right you import Vue from 'vue' in single component?

Generally, yes. If you create a new Vue project from scratch via `vue-cli` you will see how the default components import Vue from 'vue'.

Now, this doesn't mean you should configure plugins in sfc. This code from the vue chartkick page:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Chartkick from 'vue-chartkick'
import Chart from 'chart.js'

Vue.use(Chartkick.use(Chart))
```

Is not intended to be placed in a SFC file. Usually, in a Vue project, you have a `main.js` file where you setup Vue. You would do this there, in main.js. In the same main.js file you would also setup any other plugins.

You should call `Vue.use(plugin)` **before** calling `new Vue(...)` to kickstart your Vue instance, so don't add plugins in SFC.

Comment: And when I place this in main.js, how can I call it in a single component?

Comment: From the main page, it seems that once you configure chartkick you can use `<line-chart>` and other chart components in your components templates right away, but I never tried this library.